# Execution of non php files vulnerability

Tags: magento-1.8, security, apache2, centos

The magento team detail a remote code execution bug here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/security-add-handler

The test is to create a file eg test.php.csv and see if it can be executed by browsing to it. Here is the content quoted on the site

```
<?php
 phpinfo()
```

When I browse to this file, it does nothing. However, to me it does not appear to be correct PHP, and if I change the code to the following:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

then the file CAN be executed. So firstly, is article wrong, or was I wrong to "correct" the test?

Secondly, the following directive is simply not present in my config

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

And adding the other bits of code quoted in that article seems to make no difference at all.

I feel I'm missing the jist of something here. Additionally, magento is full of files that contain php but don't have a php extension (eg .phtml) so I feel the suggested change would break that - although I could specify .phtml files to be executed by the same handler - not too sure how that sits with URL rewrites though.

I'm using Centos 6. We use PHP from the [remi repsitory](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/el5.i386/remi-release-5-4.el5.remi.noarch.rpm) as per the magento setup guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are right, the code lacks a semicolon to be valid PHP (however, the closing tag `?>` is not necessary *at the end of a file*
2. Search for `AddHandler` and `SetHandler` in all configuration files (for example using `grep -r Handler /etc/apache2`) and also in your `.htaccess` files, you might have missed it
3. phtml files should not be executable on their own anyway, so it's fine. This handler configuration only applied for direct requests, not for `include` in PHP. **Side note:** No configuration will stop you from doing `include 'php.csv';` (which would execute PHP code in php.csv)

Comment: Thanks. In the case of CentOS the place to search is /etc/httpd. I found the offending lines in php.conf, changed as per the article I originally sited and now it's fixed. On a newer installation from the same repositories, the config was correct already.